# Has QGIS 1.7 been released as a stable version yet?

Tags: qgis

Has QGIS 1.7 been released as a stable version yet?

I see on the QGIS site the windows download on the is still referring to 1.6 and the OSGEO4W install has 1.6.0-7 as the stable release.

I had seen some links [here](http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Release_Checklist_1.7) and [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/milestone/Version%201.7.0) among others which referred to March/April for a release. I'm not unhappy with the timeline, I'm just curious that I might have missed something.

Thanks

Ando

Comment: This question is too ephemeral. In days or weeks it will be meaningless. It would be better discussed in chat.

Comment: Apologies. I'll take note for future questions.

Comment: s'alright ;-) in the grand scheme it's a small misstep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No QGIS 1.7 is not out yet as a proper release.  There will be a release very soon.

The release was delayed as the development team moved over to using Git for version control and the idea was also to use a new bug tracking platform before the release, however the new bug tracking is going to wait until after the release as everyone has been busy.

Comment: Sweet.....I wasn't sure if I was looking in the wrong places.

Comment: The mailing lists are the best place to keep up to speed with what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

For OSGeo4W "1.6.0-7" means version 1.6.0, package version 7. For example ([and more info](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/PackagingInstructions)):

[image: OSGeo4w package naming]

If you are keen to try out the development snapshot, you can install qgis-dev, but it isn't stable.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS Version 1.7.0 'Wroclaw' is released today i.e, on 19 June 2011.Here is the [News](http://qgis.org/component/content/article/127-qgis-1-7-release.html). You can download it [here](http://download.qgis.org/)